# Is ORC File with Snappy Compression Splittable at Stripe?

Tags: hadoop, hive, snappy, orc

Is ORC File with Snappy Compression Splittable at stripes?
As far as i know Snappy Compressed File is not splittable.
But i have read in a blog that snappy compressed file is splittable at stripes.
Is that true?

Comment: From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC it is clear that an ORC file is divided into **independent** "stripes", and the stripe footer *(which contains some metadata i.e. min/max values for each column)* can be accessed directly, with something like a `seek()`. I wonder how it could be done if the compression was done at file level... so I tend to believe the blogs that assert that compression is done at stripe+column level.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own `InputFormat` class, I don't believe `OrcInputFormat` or `OrcNewInputFormat` support splitting at the stripe level.